# UI Testing for multi screen setups

Tags: gui-design, usability-testing, multiple-devices

I was wondering if there was any tools/ systems, that are capable of simulating multiple screens for use on UI testing.

Context:
We are developing an application which can consist of multiple windows, depending on the user setup. We would like to test (manually) such setups with more than 2 monitors, even if the developer/ tester only has 1-2 monitors. We do not need to automate this testing. Being able to view it from time to time when we make larger UI changes would be sufficient.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this question is suitable for ux.stackexchange. Even the goal is UI testing, your question is about software tools... Anyway, why you don't use multiple windows/ browsers/ virtual machines?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any, but in a situation like this I would choose to perform a contextual inquiry instead of looking for a specific tool. I would sit next to the user who uses two monitors and see why/how etc. are they doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

When the target customer is using a very idiosyncratic configuration of their hardware it’s often much easier to usability test directly in that participant’s own environment. Any simulation is likely to miss some core usage patterns that are particular to that user (e.g. I have three monitors but one is set aside for my email, so I’m unlikely to use that display to run your app, or if I have four monitors but they’re arranged to make it impossible to see screen one and four at the same time).

During development you should seriously consider just investing in extra monitors for the devs to reduce the complexity in testing, but at a pinch you can probably use virtual desktops to simulate more displays; it’s baked into macOS and Windows 11 and most Linux distros.